# C++ throwing exception in recursive algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

Unhandled exception has been thrown and I need more information than:
Unhandled exception at 0x013D62E9 in Program.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x001D2F30).

It is in recursive algorithm filling form with color, pixel per pixel to all directions.Thanks

Comment: *"and I need more information"* So do we. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Is it an array, picture, pointer?? I really donť know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Stack overflow" means that your recursive function calls itself too many times than the system can support it. Either you have an error, and recursion goes to infinity, or the function is correct, but just needs the depth that system currently can't provide. We cannot tell which of the two is it until we see the code, and you tell us what the code is supposed to do.